# What should I do when i cancel a NSOperation? It did not remove from queue when I cancel it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsoperation

As I know, a NSOperation will remove from its NSOperationQueue when I send isFinished KVO notification and isFinished=YES, and will not remove from its NSOperationQueue when I send isCancelled KVO notification. so in my cancel function:

1. When the operation has cancelled before, just return.
2. When the operation is finished, just just return.
3. When a NSOperation isExecuting, its queue has send isExecuting KVO notification before, so I just send isCancelled and isFinished KVO notification, then its queue will remove it.
4. When a NSOperation isReady, its queue has not send isExecuting KVO notification yet, so I send isExecuting KVO notification, but I got some errors in console: went isFinished=YES without being started by the queue it is in.

My question is: What should I do when I cancel an operation which state is just ready? I want it to be removed by queue.

By the way, I have a member variable to save the sate of operation, I want the cancel function do not influence its value, so When cancel an operation which state is ready, I just send isExecuting KVO notification but isExecuting=NO, because the state value is ready. Finally, my code is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've read that several times, and I still can't figure out what you are asking.

Comment: Please post code , not screen shots.